# Branch.io returns {} when use Branch.getInstance().setIdentity("your_user_id");

Tags: android, branch.io, referrals

I am getting BranchSDK: `returned {}` as response
 when i use  `Branch.getInstance().setIdentity("your_user_id");`

Comment: @Sharnjeet Kaur check out my updated answer

Comment: It looks like there is some issue with your configuration of the Branch SDK. Can you write to `integrations@branch.io`?

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh it is already given in the docs maybe he is using old sdk version cause i answer that i have given is valid for the latest sdk

Comment: @Sharanjeet check out firebase dynamic links, an alternative to Branch.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a branch instance back use this method
  `Branch branch = Branch.getAutoInstance(context,"your branch key");`

as per the docs

> Singleton method to return the pre-initialised, or newly initialise
>   and return, a singleton object of the type Branch.

After that use can use singleton Branch object throughout your appp

Comment: the method that you have given i used to initialize the Branch instance. The getAutoInstance() method is used in the Application class and not the Activity Class. Please check the documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#load-branch)

Comment: So you cannot use `Branch.getAutoInstance()` in your Activity to get the Branch instance.

Comment: Yup what about it